# Typescript: Returned type depending on enum key

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, enums, overloading

I create class builder. But i cant set return type depending on enum key.

```
enum TestKeys {
  testBoolean,
  testString,
}

type SettingsKeyReturnType = {
  [TestKeys.testBoolean]: Test<boolean>,
  [TestKeys.testString]: Test<string>,
};

interface Test<T> {
  getData(): T;
}

class A implements Test<boolean> {
  getData(): boolean { return false; }
}

class B implements Test<string> {
  getData(): string { return 'test'; }
}

function buildTest<T extends keyof SettingsKeyReturnType>(key: T): SettingsKeyReturnType[T] {
  if (typeof key === 'boolean') { return new A(); }
  if (typeof key === 'string') {  return new B(); }
  
  throw new Error('Key not found');
}
```

Every return send error:

```
TS2322: Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'SettingsKeyReturnType[T]'.
   Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'Test<boolean> & Test<string>'.
     Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'Test<string>'.
       The types returned by 'getData()' are incompatible between these types.
         Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Try check T extends. Bit its not working:

```
function buildTest<T extends keyof SettingsKeyReturnType>(key: T): T extends TestKeys.testBoolean ? Test<boolean> : Test<string> {
```

Send errors:

```
TS2322: Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'T extends TestKeys.testBoolean ? Test  : Test '.
TS2322: Type 'B' is not assignable to type 'T extends TestKeys.testBoolean ? Test  : Test '.
```

The only working thing I found is:

```
function buildTest<T extends keyof SettingsKeyReturnType>(key: T): SettingsKeyReturnType[keyof SettingsKeyReturnType] {
```

But. Return type does not depend on enum.

Comment: Have you considered using overloads instead?

Comment: No. I dont try. Its really work:
`function buildTest(key: TestKeys.testString): Test<string>;`
`function buildTest(key: TestKeys.testBoolean): Test<boolean>;`
`function buildTest(key: unknown): unknown {`
but i not sure what is the best way

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could do... At least it does not show errors, and you are able to get correct type calling `getData`:

```
enum TestKeys {
  testBoolean,
  testString,
}

type SettingsKeyReturnType<T extends string | boolean> = {
  [TestKeys.testBoolean]: Test<T>,
  [TestKeys.testString]: Test<T>,
};

interface Test<T> {
  getData(): T;
}

class A implements Test<boolean> {
  getData(): boolean { return false; }
}

class B implements Test<string> {
  getData(): string { return 'test'; }
}

function buildTest<T extends keyof SettingsKeyReturnType<string | boolean>>(key: T): SettingsKeyReturnType<string | boolean>[T] {
  if (typeof key === 'boolean') { return new A(); }
  if (typeof key === 'string') {  return new B(); }

  throw new Error('Key not found');
}
```

Comment: Its work. But if i have many types its looks like 'any'